# Assign bash variables from one awk command?

Tags: bash, awk

Hoping someone can help me make my awk commands more efficient please!

Let's say my text file has around 30 lines of this type of thing:

```
ENTIRE:11.3.28.4.0
OSVER:Solaris11
VARFREE:3G
```

I'm assigning these to variables in a bash script like this:

```
ENTIRE=$(awk -F\: '$1 ~ /ENTIRE/ {print $2}' $HOSTFILE)
RELEASE=$(awk -F\: '$1 ~ /RELEASE/ {print $2}' $HOSTFILE)
OSVER=$(awk -F\: '$1 ~ /OSVER/ {print $2}' $HOSTFILE)
```

Because I have around 30 of these, it means awk is run 30 times, which is slow, and clearly not the best way.

Can anyone suggest how I can build these into one awk command please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `:` with `=` and source the file.

Comment: For these kind of requirements only array was invented, where you could keep same kind of data in array items without creating separate separate variables for each value. If you could let us know your requirement more clearly then we could help you more on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `awk` at all. If modifying the original file isn't an option, use a `while` loop and the `declare` command to define each variable.

```
while IFS=: read name value; do
    declare "$name=$value"
done < "$HOSTFILE"
```

An example:

```
$ IFS=: read name value <<< "foo:bar"
$ declare "$name=$value"
$ echo "$foo"
bar
```

Comment: Thanks guys - all much better methods than my awk method, appreciate the feedback!